# Detect the time when the user talk SpeechRecognition API?

Tags: javascript, webkit, webspeech-api, webkitspeechrecognition

I am trying to detect when the user pauses and start talking again without stop recognizing. This is the code I set to detect when the user talks and output it to the page:

```js
//set up vars
var final_transcript;
var recognizing = false;
//check if using chrome and up to date
if ('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window) {
//init
  var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();

  recognition.continuous = true;
  recognition.interimResults = true;

  recognition.onstart = function() {
    recognizing = true;
  };
//if there is error somewhere
  recognition.onerror = function(event) {
    console.log(event.error);
  };


  recognition.onend = function() {
    recognizing = false;
  };
//after giving the spech
  recognition.onresult = function(event) {
    var interim_transcript = '';
    for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
      if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
        // finilize and show the compleated text
        final_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
      } else {
        // run the speech and output it 
        interim_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;

      }
    }
    final_transcript = capitalize(final_transcript);
    final_span.innerHTML = linebreak(final_transcript);
    interim_span.innerHTML = linebreak(interim_transcript);

  };
}

var two_line = /\n\n/g;
var one_line = /\n/g;
function linebreak(s) {
  return s.replace(two_line, '<p></p>').replace(one_line, '<br>');
}

function capitalize(s) {
  return s.replace(s.substr(0,1), function(m) { return m.toUpperCase(); });
}

function startDictation(event) {
  if (recognizing) {
    recognition.stop();
    return;
  }
  final_transcript = '';
  recognition.lang = 'en';
  recognition.start();
}
//startDictation();
```

```html
<div id="results">
        <span id="final_span" class="final"></span>
        <span id="interim_span" class="interim"></span>

    </div>
```

So is there a way to detect when the user pauses and the length of time he paused?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but it's start.

https://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/7uygdyy1/1/

I'm not sure if the `onspeechstart` event only fires once, or if it would fire again if I was in a less noisy area.

If it fires multiple times, this becomes very easy to do since we can store `speech start` and `speech end` times and figure out the periods of silence from there.

If it `onspeechstart` only fires once, then you can probably find a way to get the average speech duration given text and figure out silences from there.

There is, however, an event that fires each time words are captured: `onresult`.

So the basic idea is to define an array of `activity` that you can `push` speech data into, and then analyze periods of silence afterwards.

Code:

```
let activity = []

recognition.onresult = event => {
  console.log(event)
  activity.push('Ended:' + event.timeStamp)
}

recognition.onspeechstart = event => {
  activity.push('Started:' + event.timeStamp)
}

recognition.onend = event => {
  console.log(activity)
}
```

Comment: This works great but I have one last issue, I would like to show the text when I click on 'END'. So this is what I tried https://jsfiddle.net/rp45c1rw/ , I added the console.log to the window.end function and it returned undefined so is there a way to have even show on the window.end ?